# Find an irrational number that does not contain strings of $0$s of arbitrary length in decimal notation

Tags: number-theory

> Find an irrational number that does not contain strings of $0$s of arbitrary length in its decimal representation.

I was wondering how to find such a number. Since it is irrational, the decimal cannot repeat. How do we make sure it does not contain strings of $0$s of arbitrary length in decimal notation?

Comment: Hint: you can build an irrational number using just digits $1$ and $2$ as long as you make sure that the decimal expansion is not periodic.

Comment: Don't use any zero digits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about
$$0.121122111222111122221111122222\dots$$
where the digits come in alternating blocks of $1$s and $2$s, with the lengths of the blocks increasing.  It never repeats, and contains nothing but $1$s and $2$s.

Comment: And we can even avoid arbitrarily long blocks of *any* digit: e.g. $$0.122121121212212121211212121212...$$ (that is, $12$, $2121$, $121212$, $21212121$, . . . ).